# WSO2 - SSL troubleshooting: ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Tags: ssl, wso2

I'm following this procedure to create a certificate for my WSO2 website: Create Keystore, Export the public cert,  Import the public cert to truststore, Copy jks files to servers.
I use CN= local.wso2.com and in my hosts file there is the mapping 127.0.0.1       local.wso2.com
My browser ( Chrome and Edge ) send the error "NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID" with the url "local.wso2.com:9443/carbon/"
I can go on in interactive mode but I'd like to create a correct certificate, some ideas?

Comment: I found that using localhost and wso2carbon.jks from installation my browser hasn't  the error "ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID".
I tried the procedure in this site
https://medium.com/@igunawardana/how-to-change-hostname-in-wso2-is-with-self-signed-certificate-ea547605e015
but No success for the moment.